# GCM gives me random Unauthorized 401 errors (PHP CURL)

Tags: php, android, curl, google-cloud-messaging

I just  implemented my PHP server to send messages over the Google Cloud Messaging Service to my Android device, using CURL.

Everything works fine: I run the script, the message gets sent and successfully received on my mobile device.

Or at least sometimes it does. Sometimes it returns the 401 Unauthorized error.
If I run the script 10 times, the error will occour approximately 1-4 times.

The only solution I can come up with right now is putting the whole code into a `while($unauthorized) { ... }` block, so it will retry sending the message until it gets a HTTP 200 response.

Any other suggestions? Has anyone else experienced this? What could cause this behavior?

Comment: I encountered same bug just now. Not sure why it happens. At first I'd get 401 every single time (with the correct server API key). Then I chose to regenerate key, and with the new one, it works better - now I get a 60-80% success ratio. Not sure why, though.